# +++x unexpected type required: variable found: value

Tags: java

This may be the silly question but i have no idea why it is so.I have written following code snippet.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String... str)
{
    int y = 9;
    int z = +++y; //unexpected type required:variable found:value
    int w = +-+y; // Not Error
}}
```

**Why +-+y works and +++y Not ?**

Comment: People asked Einstein the same question  :O :D

Comment: @MightyPork why does it matter? Is this question less relevant because it has no practical applications? It is a good question.

Comment: I don't think this will cause a technological revolution, though :P

Comment: @GiladNaaman What is it good for then, if it has no practical use?

Comment: @MightyPork For enriching his personal and general knowledge

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`+++y` is interpreted as the `++` operator followed by `+y`.

`+y` is as valid as `-y` is, but the `++` operator expects a variable to operate on (it cannot increment a value), and `+y` is considered a value (an addition operation was performed).

`+-+y` as `0 + (0 - (0 + y))`, and it has no increment or decrement operators with in it, so even though the operation transform the whole expression into a value (instead of a variable reference) it has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, the characters `+++` mean `++`, followed by `+`, which are two different operators. On the other hand, there is no operator `+-`, so the characters `+-+` mean `+`, then `-`, then `+`.

If you want to play with these operators, there's also `~`, which is a *binary not*. You can build arbitrary chains with the operators `+`, `-` and `~`, as long as they don't contain `++` or `--`.